# Completely "Mirror" or copy an SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, copy, backup, restore, mirror

We have some machines storing experimental data on Win7 Machines. The experimental software is only compatible with Windows 7 and as such our IT department does not want to connect to this isolated machine anymore. Is there a way to completely "mirror" this Win7 PCs SQL server or completely copy it, and keep it relatively up to date, on a win 10 PC? and by server I mean multiple databases which may grow 
in number. Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of sister site question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52007/how-do-i-move-sql-server-database-files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to completely "mirror" this Win7 PCs SQL server or
>   completely copy it, and keep it relatively up to date

What you seem to want is [`LOG SHIPPING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). The basic steps are:

- Back Up your DB
- Restore it on N number of other servers that you want to keep *relatively up to date*
- Configure log shipping, either through he wizard or manually. This will *ship* the transaction log backups to your other servers
- Restore the transaction logs

Of course, this is all automated once you set it up. The *relatively* up to date is based on how often you do the transaction log backups, how long it takes to travel, and how long it takes to restore. If you only want it updated daily, or weekly, or some other time--you could just copy your DB backups to each of the other servers via PowerShell or what ever method you want, and restore the FullBackup instead of all of the transaction logs. This is a lot simpler, and the only downtime would be during the restore of your secondary servers (how ever long the restore takes).

There are other options which include [Database Mirroring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and [Availability Groups.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) Each have their own pros and cons, and come at a price.